# React Navigation navigation.navigate("SomeScreen") error in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

A common error which occurs in `react-navigation`, when using TypeScript, is:

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ key: string; params?: undefined; merge?: boolean | undefined; } | { name: never; key?: string | undefined; params: never; merge?: boolean | undefined; }'

What could this be caused by?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This occurs when types for specific screens have not been defined.

I will describe setting up types for the stack navigation, usage in the `useNavigation` hook, as well as passing the `{navigation}` through props to a screen.

**First, setup the Stack Navigator**:

```
/**
* Types for Stack Navigator.
*/
export type StackParamList = {
  Main: undefined;
  Home: undefined;
};

const Stack = createStackNavigator<StackParamList>();
```

**When using the `useNavigation` hook:**

```
import { StackNavigationProp } from "@react-navigation/stack";

/**
 * Types for the Stack Navigator.
 */
export type StackNavigation = StackNavigationProp<StackParamList>;

const navigation = useNavigation<StackNavigation>();
```

**When passing the navigation down as a prop in a screen:**

```
/**
 * Types for passing the navigation props to screens in the Stack Navigator.
*/
export type StackNavigationProps = {
  navigation: StackNavigation;
};

const SomeScreenInTheStack = ({ navigation }: StackNavigationProps) => {
...
}
```

I extended the answer in another question, just like this, but come to find the OP is not tagging the post correctly so I created this Q&A.

Hope this is useful to someone!